# Moodle Instalation database and php setting issue

Tags: moodle, php-ini

I am trying to install moodle into my local system. and i am stuck here.

[image: screenshot]

even i update the php.ini file useing this ref link- https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/OPcache

still no success please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your mysql server version is too low and is preventing you from installing.

With regard to opcache - create a phpinfo file somewhere, and ensure the path to the config file matches what you expect.

`<?php phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your DATABASE, Opcache is recommended but not required.

SOLUTION

1. SSH into your Hosting Account via putty, 
   Bluehost provides a step by step tutorial on this and could be applied to other hosts

   - https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/putty
2. Run the Moodle Script below On the Command line Interface on PUTTY

_

```
 $cd /USER/public_html/moodle/
 $php admin/cli/mysql_compressed_rows.php -l (Lists faulty tables)
 $php admin/cli/mysql_compressed_rows.php -f (Fixes faulty tables)
```

3. Reload the install page, you should be able to proceed.

Read more: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=312863